# Poder filtrar los valores menores a 12 en sentencia sql

Tags: sql

Estimados vengo con una pequeña duda que a lo mejor me puedan ayudar a solventar, tengo la siguiente sentencia sql que funciona pero lo que necesito es al final que los valores menores a 12 no aparezcan

```
SELECT SUM(T.HORAS+T.PRODUCCION+T.DESCUENTO) AS TOTAL 
FROM( SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD, E.EMPL_APELL+' '+E.EMPL_NOMB AS OBRERO ,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_VHORA),0) FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND MOV_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS HORAS,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DES_DESCUENTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_DESCUENTO WHERE DES_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (DES_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND DES_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS DESCUENTO, 
(SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.EMPL_AREA )AS AREAS,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_TOTALCOSTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND MOV_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS PRODUCCION
FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E) AS T , TBL_EMPLEADO TBE
WHERE TBE.EMPL_NOTA = 'T' AND TBE.EMPL_COD = T.COD AND (T.HORAS>0 OR T.DESCUENTO>0 OR T.PRODUCCION>0)
GROUP BY T.COD, T.OBRERO
ORDER BY T.OBRERO
```

Adjunto una imagen de como actualmente se muestra y en la cual señalo cual no necesita que aparezca en el resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las condiciones a las funciones de agrupación se pueden realizar con Having

```
Select Sum(t.horas + t.produccion + t.descuento) As total
       From (
              Select e.empl_cod As cod
                   , e.empl_apell + ' ' + e.empl_nomb As obrero
                   , (
                       Select ISNULL(Sum(mov_vhora), 0)
                              From his_mov_hora
                              Where mov_codempleado = e.empl_cod And mov_fecha >= '26/10/2020' And mov_fecha <= '01/11/2020'
                     ) As horas
                   , (
                       Select ISNULL(Sum(des_descuento), 0)
                              From his_mov_descuento
                              Where des_codempleado = e.empl_cod And des_fecha >= '26/10/2020' And des_fecha <= '01/11/2020'
                     ) As descuento
                   , (
                       Select Distinct 
                              s.seccion
                              From tbl_seccion As s
                              Where s.id_codigo = e.empl_area
                     ) As areas
                   , (
                       Select ISNULL(Sum(mov_totalcosto), 0)
                              From his_mov_prod
                              Where mov_codempleado = e.empl_cod And mov_fecha >= '26/10/2020' And mov_fecha <= '01/11/2020'
                     ) As produccion
                     From tbl_empleado As e
            ) As t
          , tbl_empleado As tbe
       Where tbe.empl_nota = 'T' And tbe.empl_cod = t.cod And (t.horas > 0 Or t.descuento > 0 Or t.produccion > 0)
       Group By t.cod
              , t.obrero
      Having Sum(t.horas + t.produccion + t.descuento) > 12
       Order By t.obrero;
```

[Having](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes envolver la consulta y agregar un filtro.

```
SELECT * FROM

(

    SELECT SUM(T.HORAS+T.PRODUCCION+T.DESCUENTO) AS TOTAL 
    FROM( SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD, E.EMPL_APELL+' '+E.EMPL_NOMB AS OBRERO ,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_VHORA),0) FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND MOV_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS HORAS,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DES_DESCUENTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_DESCUENTO WHERE DES_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (DES_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND DES_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS DESCUENTO, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.EMPL_AREA )AS AREAS,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_TOTALCOSTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>='26/10/2020' AND MOV_FECHA<='01/11/2020')) AS PRODUCCION
    FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E) AS T , TBL_EMPLEADO TBE
    WHERE TBE.EMPL_NOTA = 'T' AND TBE.EMPL_COD = T.COD AND (T.HORAS>0 OR T.DESCUENTO>0 OR T.PRODUCCION>0)
    GROUP BY T.COD, T.OBRERO


) T
WHERE T.TOTAL >= 12
ORDER BY T.OBRERO
```